# Managed platform update failing with Incorrect application version error

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk, upgrade

I have 6 Elastic Beanstalk Python 3.7 environments running the same application. Over the course of the weekend, 5 of them have successfully, automatically auto-updated to the latest platform update:

> Platform update from 64bit Amazon Linux 2 running Python 3.7 3.3.4 to 64bit Amazon Linux 2 running Python 3.7 3.3.5

Auto update has been running successfully all year but, today, one is steadfastly refusing to upgrade and is just reporting:

> FAILED - RollbackSuccessful
> Successful abort of the Managed Action.

It appears to deploy the new instance successfully and both the new and old instances get to a point where they say OK
[image]

However, instead of the old instance being shut down, after a few minutes, the new instance suddenly reports:

> Incorrect application version "app-bd432-13735_111407" (deployment
> 280). Expected version "app-bd432-13735_111407" (deployment 277).

and the upgrade is rolled back.

So far I have tried:

1. Just retrying the upgrade
2. Redeploying the latest version of the app, then retrying the upgrade
3. Performing `Rebuild environment` before trying the upgrade

But the result is the same. I can't see any indication in the logs of either instance (old, surviving or new, failing) that offers any help but will be happy to add log info if anyone can suggest a specific log to extract.

Comment: If this is for something important like a production system I'd go to AWS Support with this. Business Support pricing is fairly reasonable if your AWS spend isn't too high, 10% of your AWS bill I think.

Comment: @Tim Luckily prod had already updated with no issues. It was one of the dev environments that had failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that a parameter setting was incorrect. I had been trying to get the AutoUpdate of the platform version to go through, and that was failing silently, but when I tried to manually apply a different version of the platform I got the following message:

> Configuration validation exception: Invalid option value: '100' (Namespace:'aws:autoscaling:lanunchconfiguration', OptionName:'RootVolumeIOPS'): '100' is not a valid volume IOPS. Must be between 3000 and 16000.

[image]

Updating this parameter allowed the platform update to complete successfully. The parameter had not been changed for several months so I can only assume it had been permitted/ignored in earlier platform versions but more rigorously enforced in 3.3.5.